# how can redirect to project stage in rails by their project id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently after creating project stage page redirects to stage index but i want page to be redirected to project show page by their project id how can i do that in rails?

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @stage = @project.stages.build(stage_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stage.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_stages_path, notice: 'Stage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stage }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages
  end
```

rake routes

```
   project_stages GET    /projects/:project_id/stages(.:format)                                                   stages#index
                          POST   /projects/:project_id/stages(.:format)                                                   stages#create
        new_project_stage GET    /projects/:project_id/stages/new(.:format)                                               stages#new
       edit_project_stage GET    /projects/:project_id/stages/:id/edit(.:format)                                          stages#edit
            project_stage GET    /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#show
                          PATCH  /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#update
                          PUT    /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#update
                          DELETE /projects/:project_id/stages/:id(.:format)                                               stages#destroy
                 projects GET    /projects(.:format)                                                                      projects#index
                          POST   /projects(.:format)                                                                      projects#create
              new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                                                                  projects#new
             edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             projects#edit
                  project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#show
                          PATCH  /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#update
                          PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#update
                          DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                                                                  projects#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, use: `redirect_to project_path(@project)`

And you can even use: `redirect_to @project`

Details in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Answer (score 0):

Change `redirect_to`

```
redirect_to project_path(@project)
```

Hope that helps!